# How to implement SSO between App Center Client and MobileFirst common apps?

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-mobilefirst, isam, mobilefirst-appcenter

We want to deploy App Center Client (maybe to customize one based on App Center API) as other apps developed based on MobileFirst platform. The current environment has LDAP (TDS) and ISAM (TAM), how to implement the SSO between them?

I know we can easily to do SSO between common mobile apps based on MobileFirst Platform, but if we want add the appcenter client to SSO, how to do it?

Comment: This question is far too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: If it an urgent question you should open an IBM PMR and not a question on stack overflow. Martin, it's not broad if you know the platform in question...

Answer (score 0):

Device SSO between MFP-based applications [is indeed possible](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_configuring_device_SSO.html?lang=en).
A requirement for Device SSO to work isa connection to the *MFP Server*

The Application Center installer app is a MFP-based application as well, however this application *does not contact the MFP Server*. It contacts the *Application Center Management Server*.

So in theory, you could enable device SSO by following the user documentation (linked above), however it will be "one-sided" in the sense that it will work in the Application Center installer app **only** if the login was first done by the "regular" MFP-baed app.

Comment: Hi Idan, thanks a lot. The customer want to startup AppCenter Client and login then startup other MFP-based apps from AppCenter Client and doesnot need login again.  So this scenario cannot be implemented?

Comment: Because the AppCenter app does not connect to the MFP Server, this is not a viable option to my knowledge.